# WPF Disabling TabStop for ObjectDataProvider

Tags: wpf, itemscontrol, tabstop

I have a ObjectDataProvider of check boxes:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
        <ObjectDataProvider x:Key="checkboxes" ObjectType="{x:Type Models:Items}" />
        <DataTemplate x:Key="Item" DataType="Models:Item" >
            <CheckBox Content="{Binding Path=Name}" IsChecked="{Binding Path=Include}" />
        </DataTemplate>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate x:Key="HorizontalList" >
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </UserControl.Resources>
```

When I tab through the controls and get to the datatemplate, it looks selects the it before going to the controls inside, like this -

[image: tabstop selecting objectdataprovider]

Is there any way to turn this off?

**Conclusion**

It isn't the ObjectDataProvider, but rather the ItemsControl that needs to be turned off -

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=container,Path=ViewModel.Items}"
                          ItemTemplate="{StaticResource Item}"
                          ItemsPanel="{StaticResource HorizontalList}"
                          IsTabStop="False"/>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no problem with ObjectDataProvider in your code, just try to set `IsTabStop = false` in the container where CheckBoxes are. can you provide more xaml code from UserControl?